# How to calculate base price + offer in excel?

Tags: excel, math

I need excel formula to calculate total price of an item which sell  set of 4 costs $1 and each costs $0.30.

E.g

Water Bottle x 4 = $1
If you buy 6 then 
Water bottle x 6 = $1.60

How can I calculate that in excel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=QUOTIENT(A1,4)+MOD(A1,4)*0.3
```

where `Cell A1` has value  `6`.

[image]